# Redirect url based on end string

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to redirect many 100s of urls based on the end string "/reviews"

example.com/reviews/any-string.121/reviews to 
example.com/reviews/any-string.121/

example.com/reviews/any-string.151/reviews to 
example.com/reviews/any-string.151/

PS: 'any-string' means any string of alphabets.

Can anyone please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/reviews$ example.com/reviews/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you sir ...the following worked RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/reviews$  /reviews/$1 [R=301,L]